# How do it get character frequency and highest character frequency?

Tags: c, character, frequency

so this is my function. My main focus is to get the character frequencies and the highest character frequency.

The function below (get_letter_frequencies) is supposed to get a string example ("I am a big boy") and return the character frequencies and the highest character frequency.

> The Function should return
> i - 2
> a - 2
> m - 1
> b - 2
> g - 1
> o - 1
> y - 1
> Highest character frequency would be " iab "

My problem is with the get_letter_frequencies function. What should I arrange from the function in order to return the above output?

```
void get_letter_frequencies(const char *text, size_t len, int freq[26], int *max_freq)
{

for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] != ' ' || !(is_sentence_terminator(text[i]))) //this condition is set in order to ignore the spaces and the sentence terminators (! ? .) 
        {
            if(text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
            {
                freq[text[i] - 'a']++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        if(freq[j] >= 1)
        {
            *max_freq = freq[j];
        }
    }
```

This function below(is_sentence_terminator). Here the function checks whether the sentence finishes with a " ! ? or . " if it does not finish with one of the terminators then it is not a sentence and ignores it.

```
int is_sentence_terminator(char ch)
{

        if(ch == 33 || ch == 46 || ch == 63)
        {
            return 1;
        }else
        {
            return 0;
        }

}
```

Comment: For one thing, shouldn't your `max_freq` loop check against the prior max instead of `1`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError could you kindly explain as i did not understand you. Thank you

Comment: @chqrlie: I arranged it to remove the shouting effect :) once again, I didn't mean to shout.

Comment: @AnthonyMifsud: See Chqrlie's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- there is no need to test for special characters, comparing `text[i]` to `'a'` and `'z'` is sufficient for ASCII systems.
- in the second loop, you should update `*max_freq` only if `freq[j]` is greater than the current value, not `1`. `*max_freq` should be initialized to `0` before the loop.

In the calling code, you would also

- print the letters whose frequency is non 0.
- print all letters with the maximum frequency using one final loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
void get_letter_frequencies(const char *text, size_t len, int freq[26], int *max_freq) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        freq[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') {
            freq[text[i] - 'a']++;  // assuming ASCII
        }
    }

    *max_freq = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (*max_freq < freq[i]) {
            *max_freq = freq[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you chqrlie. I really appreciate your help :)